# Pascal - How do i sum all the numbers that can be divided by 4, must use repeat

Tags: pascal

Cant obtain a correct answer it sums incorectly and multiplicates too, i must use repeat when solving this problem, i suppose the problem is in `sum:=i+i` but i dont know how to solve it

```
program SAD;
uses crt;
var a, i, sum, prod: integer;
begin
clrscr;
sum:=0;
prod:=0;
{Sum}
repeat
for i:=1 to 26 do
if i mod 4 = 0 then sum:=i+i;
until i = 26;
{Multiplication}
repeat
for a:=1 to 26 do
if a mod 4 = 0 then prod:=a*a;
until a = 26;
writeln('Suma numerelor divizate la 4 este:', sum);
writeln('Produsul numerelor divizate la 4 este:', prod);
end.
```

Comment: Write ``sum := sum + i;``, or better ``Inc(sum, i);``

Comment: The for loops are useless, just increment the loop counter yourself inside repeat ... until

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the instruction "use repeat" probably intends that you should avoid using `for` as well.

There are a few errors in your code:

1. In the sum loop, you should add `i` to `sum`, not to itself.
2. In the prod loop, since you set `prod` to zero at the start, it will stay as zero because zero times anything is zero.  So you need to adjust the logic of your `prod` calculation so that if `prod` is zero, when the `mod 4` condition is satisfied, you set `prod` to the current value of `a`, otherwise you multiply it by `a`.

Here is some code which fixes the above points and avoids the use of `for`.

```
program Sad;
uses crt;
var
  a, i, sum, prod: integer;
begin
  clrscr;
  sum:=0;
  prod:=0;

  {Sum}
  i := 0;
  repeat
    inc(i);
    if (i mod 4) = 0 then
      sum := sum + i;
  until i = 26;

  {Multiplication}
  a :=0;
  repeat
    inc(a);
    if a mod 4 = 0 then begin
      if prod = 0 then
        prod := a
      else
        prod := prod * a;
    end;
  until a = 26;
  writeln('Suma numerelor divizate la 4 este:', sum);
  writeln('Produsul numerelor divizate la 4 este:', prod);
  readln;
end.
```